# JQuery image resizing appears on the whole screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i added jQuery function for resizing the profile picture to fit a div (200px 200px and not sure if the function is the right one), but every time i refresh the page the function is executed again and the picture appears at the whole screen for just a second! How can i prevent this? My function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.profile-picture img').each(function() {

        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();

        if(width > height) {
            $(this).css("max-width", "100%");
            $(this).css("height", "100%");
        }else {
            $(this).css("width", "100%");
            $(this).css("max-height", "100%");
        }
    });
});
```

In one post i found answer that was saying: "You have to do it with callback", but do not know how. Can you give me advice? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It does this because the page is not rendered until your `$(document).ready` (is ready).  The best way to prevent this is to load your picture by AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.ready()` event triggers after the page has been rendered by the browser. To prevent the issue you're describing you should set some defaults in the CSS.

Going a step further, you could set all the style in the CSS then only play with the class in Javascript instead.

CSS:

```
.profile-picture {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.profile-picture img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.profile-picture img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.profile-picture img').each(function() {
    if($(this).width() < $(this).height()) {
      $(this).addClass('tall');
    }
  });
});
```